# Can a webpack powered script know the name of the webpack entry point that's calling it?

Tags: webpack

I want to have many entries in my webpack.config.js`, pointing to the same file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['./index.js'],
        mobile: ['./index.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name]/bundle.js'
    }
};
```

Is there any nice way to know from inside index.js the name of the entry point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [callback-loader](https://github.com/Kreozot/callback-loader) for this (with different configs on each entry point). But I really recommend you to refactor your code instead and use different entry points. What you want to do is kinda dirty hack.

Comment: if I refactor my code to point to multiple files, I actually have to create multiple files, I wanted multiple bundles starting with the same file. I actually achieved that with preprocess-loader, but thinking about it now, I guess it would've looked cleaner with callback-loader.